# symfony Jms error argument 2 passed must be an instance of Doctrine\Common\Persistence\ManagerRegistry

Tags: php, symfony

I have this error when trying to deserialize JSON data:

> Uncaught Error: Argument 2 passed to
> JMS\Serializer\Metadata\Driver\AbstractDoctrineTypeDriver::__construct()
> must be an instance of Doctrine\Common\Persistence\ManagerRegistry,
> instance of Doctrine\Bundle\DoctrineBundle\Registry given,   called in
> /var/www/mda-api/var/cache/prod/ContainerXJGxuAr/getJmsSerializer_MetadataDriverService.php
> on line 13

```
$result = $this->serializer->deserialize(
    $encoder->encode($jsonContent,'json'),
    Client::class,
    "json",
);
```

Does anyone have any idea why this error happen?

Comment: Could you provide versions of `jms/serializer-bundle` , `doctrine/doctrine-bundle` and `symfony`? It seems, that the `jms/serializer-bundle` version is not compatible with the `doctrine/doctrine-bundle` version

Comment: yes , "jms/serializer-bundle": "^1.0 | ^2.4", "doctrine/doctrine-bundle": "^1.11", symfony : 4.1